# Why I can change the x axis? R

Tags: r, axis

I tried to run the following script to change the x axis. I followed other answers given in Stack Overflow; however I don’t get what I’m looking for. The original x axis goes from 0 to 1 but I want to change it from 0 to 20.

```
x<-c(0,0.1,0.2,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.60,0.90,1)
y<-c(0,0.014,0.41165,0.258,0.57,0.57,0.1803,0.5844,0.10185,0.085)
da<-cbind(x,y)
dat=data.frame(da)
plot(y~x,data=dat,xaxt="n")
pas=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
axis(1, at=1:20,labels=pas)
```

This script produces a figure with just a 0 at the last mark. I need a x axis from 0 to 20. Thanks

Comment: You can call `plot` as follows `plot(y ~ x, data = dat, xaxt = "n", xlim = c(0,20))`

Comment: A few comments, the number of elements in `x` is 10 but in `y` it is 11.  `pas` can be set by just doing `pas <- 0:20` (you are missing 9 in your list). You don't need `cbind` to create the data frame, you can just do something like `data.frame(x=x,y=y)`.

Comment: Ok, now the y and x have the same n. I dont want to change the xlim. I want to force the x axis to have different values. from 0 to 20 instead from 0 to 1. Thats why I want to create a new label for the x axis. Do I explain myself?

Comment: It still needs clarification.  The `xlim` parameter does label the axis with 0 to 20.  Do you mean you want to map your `x` values to the 0 to 20 range ? If so, why ?

Comment: I dont want to map my x values. I want to change the labels of the x axis. I want to ignore the real x labels and introduce new ones.

Comment: If after calling `plot(y ~ x, data = dat, xaxt = "n", xlim = c(0,20))` you call `axis(1, at = pas, labels = pas, cex.axis=0.65)`, you should have the labels you want.  The `cex.axis` parameter is there to show how to shrink the text in case all values are not showing (this will happen when `axis` determines the labels will overlap, I believe).

Comment: Steveb, I see your point, but thats not what I want. I need to introduce a completely new label at the x axis. So, I dont want to extend the x axis by giving a new xlim=c(0,20). What I nedd is to change the labels of the x-axis so: 
0=0,
0.1=2,
0.2=4,
etc,
1=20.
Do I explain myself now now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to do this but the following would work.

```
x        <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.60,0.90,1)
y        <- c(0,0.014,0.41165,0.258,0.57,0.57,0.1803,0.5844,0.10185,0.085)
dat      <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
x.range  <- c(0,20)
x.labels <- x.range[1]:x.range[2]
pas      <- seq(0, 1, length.out = length(x.labels))
plot(y ~ x, data = dat, xaxt = "n", xlim = c(0,1))
axis(1, at = pas, labels = x.labels, cex.axis=0.65)
```

[image]

Comment: Great Steveb! Thats exactly what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Cebs just to be clear, if you prefer the `ggplot` answer you should accept that.  Which ever one most appropriately answers the questions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed the xlim/ylim.

Did you mean y axis? Then just use :

```
plot(y~x,data=dat,ylim=c(0,20))
```

`plot(y~x,data=dat,xlim=c(0,20))`# you need to remove the 'xaxt="n"' to see the x-axis

Although either way I am not sure this is the best idea given the range of the data.

## Using ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y,data=dat)+ scale_x_continuous(labels=c("0"="fake0","0.25"="fake5","0.5"="fake10",".75"="fake15","1"="fake20"))# replace 'fake#' with anything
```

[image: plot custom x]
Although I am not sure why are you trying to do this.

Comment: Thanks but my intention is to change the x-axis completely... Not to introduce a different xlim. Now, as you can se the x axis is from  to 1. But I want to change the label of the axis from 0 to 20...

Comment: Easy way is to transform x-values by multiplying with 20 and using xlim. But must admit this is a bit strange. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is just an example. In my real preoblem I need to transform the x axis after plotting not before. If i try to multiply the x-axis after plotting I still not getting it. The problem is with the axis function. But I dont know where is the problem

x<-c(0,0.1,0.2,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.60,0.90,1);
y<-c(0,0.014,0.41165,0.258,0.57,0.57,0.1803,0.5844,0.10185,0.085);
da<-cbind(x,y);
dat=data.frame(da);
plot(y~x,data=dat,xaxt="n");
axis(1,x*20,);

Comment: If modifying x-axis  tick labels is what you want, I have added an edit with ggplot2